# Changing legal name, what happens when I visit the US again?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, esta

I'm a UK Citizen, I have previously visited the US under the name of, let's say, Joe Smith. I am changing my name to, let's say, Joe Barnes.

My passport will be in the new name of Barnes.

Do I have to acquire a new ESTA? And what happens when I visit the US? Will those machines that print off the slip show my old name or new name? And will this lead to more questioning on entry?

Comment: You need a new ESTA whenever you get a new passport, regardless of the name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need a new ESTA:

https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization

> If you obtain a new passport or **change your name**, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes. The associated fee of $14 will be charged for each new application.

Comment: Your ESTA must match your travel docs.  It is that simple.

Answer (score 6):

When getting a new passport, a new ESTA is required, whether you changed your name or not.

The kiosk receipt will contain your current passport data.